# Show alert message after confirm message with link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alert, link-to

I want to show a alert message just after confirm message launched by a link_to on Rails 3.2.11 into a haml. I mean, I'll to ask for confirm the action, then I show a message (alert) with the confirmation.

I have the following code:

```
= link_to([:archive, :admin, campaign], method: :put, confirm: t('are_you_sure_archive'))
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Look for the "A warning message, with a function attached to the "Confirm"-button..." example

There is a gem for sweetalert

Comment: Awesome! It was great! and it was accepted by the team!